# Create a Virtual directory inside a asp.net mvc 3 application in iis

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I am having an asp.net mvc3 application running in IIS. I am trying to add a virtual directory inside the asp.net mvc application which host another application.

http://localhost/Test1/Test2/Index.mvc/index

Test1- Mvc 3 application which works fine 
Test2- another mvc application created in as a virtual directory inside test1.

How do i set my route to load the appropriate application. Is there any configuration i need to do for the application to work properly in iis.

Thanks, 
Pawan

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an IIS application instead of a virtual directory.

Comment: It is created as an application. So when i click on a menu which has test 2. it should point to that application.

Comment: Even with Windows 2003 server, you really don't want or need to explicitly end up with that nasty url with index.mvc.  I believe Scott H. or Jon G. has write ups on deploying with 2003 and 2008 servers.  I have done both, but it is difficult to follow your question a little.

Comment: @Tom : when we deploy it to our production systems which runs on windows server 2008 and iis 7 it is just index. Its only in local host we have it as index.mvc

Comment: Ok, I see.  Links on the right side under "Related" may be helpful.

Comment: @SLaks, "need" or "must"? Suppose my hosting provider only lets me have a single application. Can I still host multiple application in subdirectories?